# Left aligned numbers in profile

Tags: discussion, design, profile-page

User Experience has a [highly upvoted answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/72230) to a question about the alignment of numbers. The answer includes:

> Left aligned numbers when listed below each other are a disaster and should be avoided. I can't think of a single case where this isn't true.

Just curious why then the Accounts listing left aligns rep and badges, eg:

[image: Alignment example]

Votes Cast right aligns and that the `rep`s do not stack neatly seems inelegant. I appreciate that rep is not normally summed across accounts but it is sometimes, and it is appearances rather than arithmetic that I am wondering about.

I ask here because I think it was on WA that I saw the post being advertised. Also WA already has a question about [vertical alignment](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2343/reputation-in-the-user-profile-is-not-vertically-aligned).