# Left-aligned numeric columns in network profile

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, numbers

In the Top Questions and Top Answers sections of one’s network profile, the post scores are misaligned. [For example](https://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet):

[image: Jon Skeet's network profile]

Notice how the 1 in the 1046 line is in the same column as the 9 in the 938 line.

As observed in [this earlier MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247949/153355), columns of numbers should always be right- not left-aligned:

> User Experience has a [highly upvoted answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/72230) to a question about the alignment of numbers. The answer includes:
>
> > Left aligned numbers when listed below each other are a disaster and should be avoided. I can't think of a single case where this isn't true.

It is conceivable that when Mr Skeet’s top answer hits the ten-thousand mark, that the formatting may switch to something like `10.1k`. But even there you can still vertically align the units column (or the decimal point). Plus [his Accounts page](https://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=accounts) suggests that this will not flip over:

[image: Jon Skeet's Network Profile's Accounts page]